# Android App fails to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, slider

I am new to android programming and, recently, a lot of my apps have been getting this error.

Here is the runtime stack trace:

```
01/26 17:02:17: Launching WelcomeActivity
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.smartswitch/com.example.android.smartswitch.WelcomeActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 4258 on device genymotion-custom_phone___7_0_0___api_24___768x1280-192.168.160.101:5555
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.smartswitch-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.android.smartswitch, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.smartswitch-2/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.smartswitch, PID: 4258
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.smartswitch/com.example.android.smartswitch.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2815)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:104)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:317)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88)
                  at com.example.android.smartswitch.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:36)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

I am trying to make an android app that has an introslider like the one [here](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/android-welcome-slider-animation-with-dots.gif). This is the MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.smartswitch;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

int controllerButton = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // but this is for testing
    slidingScreenLauncher prefManager = new slidingScreenLauncher(getApplicationContext());
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onButtonClick (View view) {
    String message = null;
    switch (view.getId())  {
        case R.id.settingsButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, logging_screen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.controllerButton:
            if (controllerButton == 1)  {
                Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controllerButton);
                button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);        //Changing the background of the controllerButton.
                button1.setText(getString(R.string.controller_off_text));
                Button headerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.headerText);
                headerButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                headerButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                headerButton.setText(getString(R.string.banner_off_text));

                controllerButton--;         //Setting the button int to zero for next change.
            }

            if (controllerButton == 0)  {
                Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controllerButton);
                button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);        //Changing the background of the controllerButton.
                button1.setText(getString(R.string.controller_on_text));
                Button headerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.headerText);
                headerButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                headerButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                headerButton.setText(getString(R.string.banner_on_text));
                controllerButton++;         //Setting the button int to one for nex change. An altering loop.
            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.scheduleSettingsSideBar) {
        //Intent to send the user to scheduleSettings Screen.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.manualSettingsSideBar) {

    } else if (id == R.id.tempSettingsSideBar) {
        //Intent to send the user to tempSettings Screen.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, temp_screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else if (id == R.id.randomDelaySideBar) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, random_delay.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.humiditySettingsSideBar) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, humidity_settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.loggingSideBar) {
        //Intent to send the user to loggingSidebar.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, logging_screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id ==R.id.generalSettingsSideBar) {

    } else if (id == R.id.playSliderAgain) {
        /* We normally won't show the welcome slider again in real app
        // but this is for testing
        slidingScreenLauncher prefManager = new slidingScreenLauncher(getApplicationContext());
        // make first time launch TRUE
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
        finish(); */
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is the WelcomActivity.java file which is supposed to display the introslider:

```
package com.example.android.smartswitch;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;
private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
private slidingScreenLauncher prefManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new slidingScreenLauncher(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            R.layout.welcome_slide3,
            R.layout.welcome_slide4};

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
  }
}
```

The shared preferences files that I have created and saved separately is working fine. The main problem is with the WelcomeActivity.java file mostly.

Lastly, here is the manifests file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.smartswitch">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".temp_screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_temp_screen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".logging_screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_logging_screen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".humidity_settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_humidity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".random_delay"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_random_delay"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?? Also, I don't know how to set the manifests so that the IntroSlider is displayed at the start and then the MainActivity begins (I am also thinking of adding a SplashScreen)

Any help is much appreciated, without this I can't even test my app and improve it....

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... It turned out to be a stupid bug!! I couldn't have got over this issues without your help @Santosh and W4R10CK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);`
```

using this twice in activity please remove it.

comment these lines

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

   // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new slidingScreenLauncher(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove twice written `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);`:

Welcome Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

//removed super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//removed setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```